# How to re-name warning messages when running pdftex

Tags: pdftex, warnings

I'm looking for a quick and dirty solution to this, however bad practice it is.

I have a bunch of warnings produced, and I can see from my outputted documentation that they're not actually 'bad'. So I'd like to, instead of giving me its normal warning message, spit out a different message.

Is it possible to go from this:
`pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier...`

to this: `Uhoh: Something bad has happened, but don't worry`?

Possibly using a command like `\renewcommand{\GenericWarning}...`

Comment: In general, you can change this, but not for these pdfTeX warning messages.

Answer (score 4):

No, this is not possible, because the warning is not generated by TeX macro code, but from the binary itself. You should resolve the issue with duplicate destination names, because you could have links targeting the wrong destination.

Comment: Ok. Maybe if I tell you why I want to do this, you'll be able to help me find a different solution. When I use the 'silence' package, the warnings go away, but latex then errors with the old '\pdfendlink ended up in different nesting level than \pdfstartlink.' error. This doesn't appear when the warnings are present. I want some way of silencing the warnings (specifically the word 'Warning') without actually getting rid of them.

Comment: @user1488804: You have to change it in the source code of pdfTeX.